# Java arraylist incompatible types error

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej, incompatibletypeerror

The answer to this will probably turn out to be obvious in retrospect but for now I find myself rather stuck on this. I'll give some blocks of code first and then present the problem.

This is part of my class Stockmanager, I have omitted some methods that have nothing to do with this problem.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StockManager
{
private ArrayList stock;

public StockManager()
{
    stock = new ArrayList();
}

public void addProduct(Product item)
{
    stock.add(item);
}

public Product findProduct(int id)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < stock.size())
    {
        Product test = stock.get(index);
        if (test.getID() == id)
        {
            return stock.get(index);
        }
        index++;
    }
    return null;
}

public void printProductDetails()
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < stock.size())
    {
        System.out.println(stock.get(index).toString());
        index++;
    }
}
```

}

Here's my class Product, again with some methods omitted.

```
public class Product
{
private int id;
private String name;
private int quantity;

public Product(int id, String name)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    quantity = 0;
}

public int getID()
{
    return id;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public int getQuantity()
{
    return quantity;
}

public String toString()
{
    return id + ": " +
           name +
           " voorraad: " + quantity;
}
```

}

My problem lies in the fact that I get a compile time error in the findProduct() method. To be more specific the line `Product test = stock.get(index);` is indicated with a message **incompatible types**.

The constructor of StockManager creates a new `ArrayList` with the name stock. As is evident from the method `addProduct()` this `ArrayList` contains items of the type `Product`. The `Product` class has a number of variables one of which is called id and is of type integer. That class also contains a method `getID()` that returns an **id**.

As far as I know, the way of getting an item from an arraylist is the `get()` method with the number between the () indicating the item's position. Seeing as my arraylist contains instances of `Product`, I expect to get a `Product` as result when I use the `get()` method on the arraylist. So I don't understand why it doesn't work when I define a variable called test of the type Product and try to assign an item from the arraylist to it. I have as far as I know, successfully used this same technique in the method `printProductDetails()` where I use the `toString()` method from Product on the object from the arraylist.

I hope someone will be able to clarify for me where I am at fault. If it makes any difference, I am doing this stuff in BlueJ which is probably not the best tool for it but it is the one I'm supposed to use for this school project.

Comment: Only have to cast `return (Product)stock.get(index);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `stock` is defined as `private ArrayList stock`, which means that `stock.get()` returns an Object without any special type. You should either make Stock an ArrayList of Products

```
ArrayList<Product> stock;
```

or cast the result of the `get` method manually

```
Product test = (Product)stock.get(whatever);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have used your first suggestion, the other one also works but then I'd have to specify the type every time I want to approach an object in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 6):

```
private ArrayList stock;
```

You should redeclare this with a bounded type like so:

```
private List<Product> stock = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

If you don't, this line:

```
Product test = stock.get(index);
```

won't work because you're trying to assign a raw `Object` to a `Product`.

Others have suggested casting the `Object` to a `Product`, but I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have managed to solve the problem by using Danstahr's suggestion of "ArrayList<Product> stock;" This one seemed a little bit simpler to me than your suggestion although I cannot judge which one would be better. Is there a difference? I am still wondering why the other method printProductDetails() did work without specifying the type for the ArrayList.

Comment: Ouch.

But anyway, `printProductDetails()` worked because you're calling `toString()`, which is defined for all java `Object`s.

Comment: @Stonelesscutter : Our answers say basically the same while this one is a bit more descriptive. ```printProductDetails()``` works just fine, because ```stock.get(index)``` returns an Object and there's a method called toString() on Object, so it looks fine to the compiler. The toString() method is called on Product object in runtime because in Java, all methods are treated as virtual.

Comment: I am perfectly fine with selecting both of your replies as the answer to my question, but unfortunately I can only pick one. If you guys are agreed I can switch it to this answer.

I think I am starting to get my head around it but I still don't see why the toString() method would be different from the getID() method since they are both defined in the same class. Doesn't the toString() method in Product supercede the general toString() method?

Comment: @Stonelesscutter: It's about this assignment : ```Product test = stock.get(index); ```. ```stock.get(index)``` returns an Object. An Object isn't-a Product, thus it cannot be assigned to a variable of Product type. You somehow need to tell the compiler that that result of the get() method is a Product. In my answer, I offered you two ways of doing that.
Plus, the toString() method is somehow special. It's already defined in Object class and you just override it in your custom class.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Both of your responses really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
Product test = (Product) stock.get(index);
```

or if you make your list `List<Product> stock` your line should work without changes.